# How to stop mu4e from inserting line breaks?

Tags: mu4e

When I write a long line while composing a mail in `mu4e`, the lines are truncated for viewing (`toggle-truncate-lines`), but as soon as I hit Enter fixed line breaks (column width seems to be 70 or something) are introduced.

How can I stop `mu4e` from introducing these line breaks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can turn off `auto-fill-mode` in the `mu4e` message buffer.  You can do so automatically by adding a function to the `mu4e-compose-mode-hook`:

```
(defun no-auto-fill ()
  "Turn off auto-fill-mode."
  (auto-fill-mode -1))

(add-hook 'mu4e-compose-mode-hook #'no-auto-fill)
```

Answer (score 6):

This will suffice in emacs nowadays:

```
(add-hook 'mu4e-compose-mode-hook 'turn-off-auto-fill)
```

Comment: I like to combine this with `(add-hook 'mu4e-compose-mode-hook 'visual-line-mode)` to have 'soft' line wrapping without actual newlines, but ensuting that the text stays inside my frame.